# magento featured products limited to 5

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, product-list

I'm using the featured products tutorial here [magento site](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/cms_and_home_page/featured_products_from_a_category_on_frontpage) but I'm finding that no matter how many items I add to my custom category, I'm limited to five items on the featured products block.

I've read around, I know this is due to a constant in the code block that generates the list, but I'm not sure how to find the generating code block.

I'm guessing the clue is in the line

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="2" template="catalog/product/featured.phtml"}}
```

and that the type="catalog/product_list" is the giveaway.

Question is, how do I know where this code is...

Thanks

Comment: I've just found the following answer, which looks comprehensively like what i need to read? [link](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6854/magento-show-featured-product-in-header?rq=1)

Answer (score 5):

You can add "column_count" to use product limit

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" column_count="5" category_id="3" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

A block of type `catalog/product_list` you look for in `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php`. Of course blocks like models van be rewritten. To check that the easiest is to use [n98-magerun](http://magerun.net/),using `n98-magerun.phar dev:module:rewrite:list |grep catalog/product_list`.